# How to make Maven use Eclipse workspace default JRE?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I'm using Spring Tool Suite and m2e to convert some of our existing projects to Maven projects. The project in question uses jdk1.6.0_20 which is named [jdk1.6] in Eclipse. When I do Maven -> Update project, though, it replaces that jre with the standard [JavaSE-1.6].  While they seem to point to the same libraries, the change in name causes a bunch of exceptions like:

> Access restriction: The type WindowsPopupMenuSeparatorUI is not
>   accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\lib\rt.jar

My pom.xml has this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is there any way to get Maven/m2e to use the default workspace JRE instead of replacing it with a specific one in the .classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with Maven. Instead I changed the error to a warning in Eclipse settings while I work with the owners of the offending code to fix the problems.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go into Configure Build Path on the project and go to the Libraries tab.
2. Remove the JRE System Library
3. Click on "Add Library..." and select "Workspace Default JRE"

That will give you the current JRE and not specify a specific JRE

Comment: I do select that, but Maven changes that property when I update the project.  It replaces the workspace default setting with a specific JRE.

Comment: Hmmm.. then check to see if the pom has a hardcoded reference to the compiler level.

Answer (score 2):

Adding maven-compiler-plugin to your pom forces maven to use given version of Java:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.3</version>
             <configuration>
                 <source>1.8</source>
                 <target>1.8</target>
             </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However **if you have both jre and jdk installed on your system** (for a particular java version), **maven may choose jre and then complain that it needs JDK**. This may happen after using Maven > **Update Project** in Eclipse.

To solve this, in Eclipse, right click on JRE System Library > Properties > Environments and select JavaSE-1.8. If you have more than one compatible JREs in your system then tick the jdk1.8.x > OK > select JavaSE-1.8 (jdk1.8.x) as Execution environment > OK

Now maven should choose Java version 1.8 and Eclipse will tell maven to use jdk1.8 as the default JRE for this java version.